# Ordered bars on plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm trying to make a CPU Usage graph with Plotly and R, I want the max usage (100%, the blue bar) on top, and the other one on bottom, but when I try this code

```
     plot_ly( x = cores, y = max, type = 'bar', name = 'Free') %>%
       add_trace( y = data, name = 'Used') %>%
       layout(
         title = "CPU Usage",
         font = list(family = 'Comic Sans MS'),
         yaxis = list(title = 'Percent'),
         xaxis = list(title = '', tickangle = -45),
         barmode = 'stack')
   })
```

It gives me the reverse, ordering the greater bar on bottom, and the orange one on top. I want to invert it.
[image: Plot Picture]

I searched on some [references](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotly/versions/4.7.1/topics/add_trace) but nothing was found about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not know your data but:

```
cores <- c("Average", "Core1", "Core2", "Core5")
Free <- c(65, 60, 80,50)
Used <- c(100-65, 40, 20,50)
data <- data.frame(cores, Free, Used)

plot_ly(data, x = ~cores, y = ~Used, type = 'bar', name = 'Used') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Free, name = 'Free') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = '%'), barmode = 'stack')
```

[image]